# Smart and customizable FTP server to grab client request and run shell script on server side

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

I don't know if this is the right place to ask a suggestion but I would have a trial.

I have a need to allow an FTP client to connect to a server requesting to download a file that does not exists but has instead to be created on demand.

Or better:
- FTP client would connect to the FTP server with user and password exchange
- FTP server will request to get file (ie) 'stefano.txt' that does not exists on server side
- FTP server has to grab such request, trigger an external daemon that creates on-the-fly 'stefano.txt' that then would be dispatched to the client

What today I have is just the FTP client (and FTP is the unique protocol I can use for data transfer).
What I need to find/develop is an FTP server daemon in charge to accept request and handle communication.

Before to develop an FTP server from scratch, is there an FTP server daemon alredy available that I can start to study and can be extended to satisfy my need?

Thanks anyone that would give me a suggestion.

Ciao,
Stefano

Comment: Why FTP? HTTP servers can already do exactly this.

Comment: Exactly as @EJP says... if the file doesn't exist, you make a `rewrite rule` that converts the filename requested into a parameter and then calls a PHP or Perl CGI script with that parameter in order to generate the file.

Comment: Thank you both.
This is a possibility that I did not evaluate but as I'm in charge of FTP server (the client is instead hardcoded on the equipment we're going to buy and it's provided by a supplier or my company) it means that I can run an http server on port 21 (the one of FTP) and it would be in charge to provide data accordingly. Is this right? And how about user/password authentication?